# Analyse eines Grammatik-Witzes

Tags: grammar-identification

Der folgende Satz wurde so ähnlich in einem Zeitungsartikel gefunden und sorgte für allseitige Belustigung.

> Zuerst schlug der Täter die Schaufensterscheibe der Firma Altendorfer
> und hiernach den Weg nach Schrattenbruck ein.

Gibt es einen Fachbegriff für dieses Stilmittel, das hier benutzt wurde? Ist es grammatikalisch korrekt wiederholte homonyme Verben auf diese Art zu kürzen?

Comment: Weil die treffendste Antwort in einem Kommentar von @KilianFoth zur verlinkten Frage enthalten ist, hier nochmals wiederholt: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_(Sprache).